# Check Screen Size and Do Something if equal or greater than 768px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a website for a university. I am trying to create a line of javascript that checks for screen size and if the screen size is greater than or equal to 768, I want it to open my images in a color box, which is defined in the university's template. Otherwise, if the screen size is less than 768, I want it to do nothing.

Currently it is just doing nothing, no matter what screen size...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowSize = $(window).width();
        if (windowSize >= 768) {
            WDN.initializePlugin('modal', [function() {
            var $ = require('jquery');
                $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
            }]);
        }
    }
    checkWidth();
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});​
```

Comment: Shouldn't your condition be >= 768

Comment: there should be a problem with your WDN.initializePlugin i think, the resize function works well for me if i insert an alert into it.

Comment: Are you sure that passing in an array with one function as the second parameter to  WDN.InitializePlugin is correct? From other code I've found I see people passing {configuartion objects} or arrays of such objects.

Answer (score 0):

And I'm seeing you're `requiring` jQuery only after the `if` condition. So, `$(document).ready()` will throw an error

Move the jquery import to the top

Condition should be

```
if (windowSize >= 768) {}
```

Comment: Okay I fixed the comparison. If I moved the jquery require to somewhere else would that maybe make it work? Maybe if I put it before the $(document).ready(function() ?

Comment: Also, without jquery $(document).ready() will fail. Why not just put it in the HTML head?

Comment: I'm using drupal, I'm not sure how to put it in the head :/